# Conditional Formatting sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional Formatting - Format row](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29816/conditional-formatting-format-row)

I'm using sharepoint 2010.

how can I implemet the "Conditional Formatting" concept om custom list.

I want to paint the list row according to the filed "Ststus",
if status = "completing" --> row color = green
if status = "not started" --> row color = blue
etc..

Comment: If you need to expand on your question please edit it rather than create a second near-identical question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

http://sp365.co.uk/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-2010-conditional-formatting/

Here's my sample (http://gyazo.com/d7b4427824dc9796e9990081430ab271.png) for your task. Note the marked areas.
[image]