# Conditional Formatting - Format row

Tags: sharepoint-designer, formatting

I'm using SharePoint 2010.

In order to implement the "conditional formatting" on my list view, 
I do so:

1. open my list in sharepoint designer
2. press on the list view
3. press on the "option" tab in the ribbon
4. press on the conditional formattinf option
5. **now I want to press on the "Fomat Row"** in order to change the row color when the tsatus field is equal to "completed".
   but the "Format Row" option block, its look like this:

[image]

**whay this option blocked? 
how can I use this option?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click inside row or cell of your ListViewWebPart in design view pane - the Conditional Formatting menu options are context sensitive. It's from my sample made for your last topic:
[image]